# aplicando charset em E-mail Marketing

Tags: css, html5, css3

Li recentemente que o ideal para a construção de um E-mail Marketing é não usar:

> - DOCTYPE
> - HTML
> - tag
> - BODY
> - tag Meta
> - tags Head
> - tag Base
> - tag Link
> - tag Script
> - tag Title
> - tag Applet
> - tag Frameset
> - tag Frame
> - tag IFrame
> - tag Comments

http://www.webstandards.blog.br/html/email-marketing-html-css/

Como resolvo os problemas de *charset*? Não devo usar o código abaixo?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Pelo que li do artigo, essa tags devem ser evitadas, mas não significa que não pode-se usar, lembrando que esse artigo é de 2010, algumas coisas podem ter mudado de lá para cá. Quando vou mandar e-mails mkt ou outros tipos costumo sempre fazer o html completo. Vou até ver se estou fazendo errado, mas nunca me deu problemas.

Comment: Opa Marcelo, eu também costumo enviar sempre com o HTML todo, porém notei de um tempo para cá que a maioria dos e-mail desenvolvidos estão caindo no spam ou lixeira, creio que por estas usabilidades, vou fazer estas alterações e ver se os dados mudam ou se mantêm.

Comment: Não sei se essas usabilidades são culpas de cair no span, umas podem ser que sim, como meta, não sei, estou só falando, mas pode estar caindo no span por outras questões de configuração do servidor de envio de e-mail, eu olharia isso antes para resolver essa questão de span.

Answer (score 1):

Vejo duas formas de resolver seu problema:

Definir o header do e-mail com o Content-Type desejado, no seu caso: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Isso pode ser feito através do seu cliente de envio de e-mails em lote. Por exemplo, no Django isso é feito definindo dessa forma:

```
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
```

O charset será definido de acordo com o charset de sua instância do Django.

A outra forma é usar os códigos ou nomes HTML dos símbolos especiais que fores enviar.

Por exemplo:

```
<p>Administração</p>
```

Fica convertido para:

```
<p>Administra&#231;&#227;o</p>
```

Ou para

```
<p>Administra&ccedil;&atilde;o</p>
```

Para isso você pode usar os seguintes conversores:

http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

http://www.emailonacid.com/character_converter/

Referências

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references